# Inserting data from one TSQL database table to another using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, bulkinsert

We are working with the following class

```
internal class Person
{
        public int BusinessEntityID { get; set; }
        public string PersonType { get; set; }
        public bool NameStyle { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public  string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Suffix { get; set; }
        public int EmailPromotion { get; set; }
        public string AdditionalContactInfo { get; set; }
        public Uri Demographics { get; set; }
        public string rowguid { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

The two databases are both active on localhost, suppose I also want to make it modular, is there any way that we can create the table inside Visual studio for the destination database so that no matter the entry it will always correspond to the end result?

This is my connection tab

```
internal class DestinationDatabase : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=localhost;Database=APIToDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=true") ;

    }
    public DbSet<Person>? Person { get; set; }
}

internal class SourceDatabase : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=localhost;Database=AdventureWorks2019;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=true");

    }
    public DbSet<Person>? Person { get; set; }
}
```

I attempted to create a reader that goes trough the entries one by one and inserts them into the destination, however I am not sure how to finalize it.

```
namespace DatabaseTransfer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sourceDatabase = new SourceDatabase();
            var destinationDatabase = new DestinationDatabase();
            var constringsource = @"Server=localhost;Database=APIToDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
            var sourcecon = new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(constringsource);
            var constringdestination = @"Server=localhost;Database=AdventureWorks2019;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
            var destinationcon = new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(constringdestination);
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Person.Person", sourcecon))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Person", destinationcon);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If its all on the same machine and presumably schemes are equal why not just  a `insert into dest.Table from select cols from source.Table`. Just create a linked server in one of the systems.

Comment: You are right, that would be the obvious decision, however I am trying to learn how to transfer data between two databases using C#,, thanks for the help though <3

Comment: you can use SqlBulkCopy  to Ado.net and Use EFCore.BulkExtensions  to EF Core

Comment: Side note: you should use `.` or the machine name instead of `localhost` as this allows it to use Shared Memory rather than TCP

Answer (score 0):

Not quite got what you are trying to achieve and why are you mixing EF Core `DbContext` with ADO.NET's `SQLConnection`,

but you could use your defined context to execute the SQL with **EF CORE** such way

```
using (var sourceContext = new SourceDatabase())
using (var destinationContext = new DestinationDatabase())
{
    var persons = sourceContext.Person.ToList();
    destinationContext.Person.AddRange(persons);
    destinationContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ADO.net SqlBulkCopy class enables quick, mass upload of records into a table:

```
string csDestination = "put here the a connection string to the database";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(csDestination))
using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
{
    connection.Open()
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "TUrls";
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTableOfUrls);
}
```

The EF BulkInsertAsync with EFCore.BulkExtensions. class enables quick, mass upload of records into a table:

```
var bulkConfig = new BulkConfig()
    {

        SetOutputIdentity = true,
                PreserveInsertOrder = true

    };
   

var ListPosts= schoolContext.Posts.ToList(); 
await schoolContext.BulkInsertAsync(ListPosts, bulkConfig);
```

Comment: You can feed a reader from one database directly to `SqlBulkCopy` there is no need for a datatable